# Create Multiple users in AD and assign a home directory

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am relatively new to using PowerShell and all scripting languages so apologies if this is a silly question.

My script is as follows:

```
$pw = read-host "Password" -AsSecureString 
Import-CSV D:\powershell_create_bulk_users\bulk_users1_Modified.csv | foreach {
New-ADUser -Name $_.Name -SamAccountName $_.SamAccountName -Surname $_.Surname - 
DisplayName $_.DisplayName -Path $_.Path -AccountPassword $pw  -ChangePasswordAtLogon 
$false  -Enabled $true 
$fullPath = '\\NAS\student\'
$driveLetter = "Z:"
$user = Get-ADUser $_.SamAccountName
Set-ADUser $User -HomeDrive $driveLetter -HomeDirectory $fullPath -ea Stop
$homeShare = New-Item -Path $fullPath -ItemType Directory -force -ea Stop
$acl = Get-Acl $homeShare
$FileSystemRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"Modify"
$AccessControlType = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow
$InheritanceFlags = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit, 
ObjectInherit"
$PropagationFlags = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]"InheritOnly"
$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ($User.SID, 
$FileSystemRights, $InheritanceFlags, $PropagationFlags, $AccessControlType)
$acl.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)
Set-Acl -Path $homeShare -AclObject $acl -ErrorAction Stop
}
```

It creates the user fine and also the drive but only \NAS\student\ and not what I ideally want which is for E.g \NAS2\student\Tsmith.

I also get an error:

```
`New-Item : The path is not of a legal form.
 At D:\powershell_create_bulk_users\bulk_users1_Modified.ps1:8 char:14
 + ... homeShare = New-Item -Path $fullPath -ItemType Directory -force -ea S ...
 +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (\\NAS\student\:String) [New-Item], 
 ArgumentException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
 CreateDirectoryArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand`
```

Was hoping someone could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you forgot to specify the name of the new home directory - `New-Item` tries to be helpful, and goes "the caller probably wants me to create a folder named `student` at the path `\\NAS`" - But `\\NAS` is not a directory, and the attempt to open it as such results in the error you see.

Change this lines:

```
$fullPath = '\\NAS\student\'
```

to:

```
$basePath = '\\NAS\student\'
# construct full home directory path for user to basepath+username
$fullPath = Join-Path $basePath -ChildPath $_.SamAccountName
```

The subsequent calls to `Set-ADUser` and `New-Item` will now create and set the home directory to `\\NAS\student\username` correctly

Comment: Awesome right this makes sense, Thaks so much for replying, And I think we are getting somewhere, I no longer get errors but a strange thing is occurring. 

The home folder that gets created is \\NAS\student\\(whatever is in the $_.Path variable)..... this is obviously incorrect as I want the \\NAS\student\username like you stated.

any ideas?

Comment: @CarlPhelps Please refresh :)

Comment: Thanks Theo that solved my issues :) 

Thanks for everyone's help, much appriciated.

Comment: @CarlPhelps If my answer solves your problem, consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left :)

Comment: All done :)

Sorry to bother you again, but the code you provided now works great and within AD it adds the correct Homefolder. 

However I don't think it is assigning the correct permissions because when you log in the \\nas\student\username folder is nowhere to be seen, and when I try to browse to it I get a permissions error. 

But my Admin account can obviously access it easy. 

Do you have any idea where I have gone wrong in the permissions section of the script?